# Attempting to power up LED backlight

Tags: voltage, led

I’m trying to power up the LED backlight panel from an old computer monitor. I tried to find documentation on the monitor model but can’t find anything regarding the voltage. Nothing on the board or led panel itself either.

I’ve resorted to trial and error. The strip inside appears to be split into two parts, sharing a wire in the center with an additional wire each. For testing purposes I’m only trying to power up one half.

I’ve been using steps of 10 volts. Up to 20 volts nothing happens in any configuration. At 30 it draws around 150 mA in one direction and no current in the other. No light from the panel though.

Before you ask, yes I tried to measure the voltage across the output from the monitor’s board. I shorted the output because the voltage probe slipped. Killed the board’s output before I could get a reading.

What voltages should I try?

Comment: Look at how many LEDs are in series on the panel.  3v per LED, from that you can calculate the voltage needed.

Comment: @user1850479 My bench power supply doesn’t go that high. Time for voltage boosters…

Comment: It appears to be 33 LEDS in series per strip

Comment: 100V sounds about right.